# Does Explicit Object Parameter Allow Convertible Types?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, this, c++23, explicit-object-parameter

From §4.2.7 of the proposal http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0847r7.html#pathological-cases

It said that:

> These are even more unlikely to be actually useful code. In this example, `B` is neither convertible to `A` nor `int`, so neither of these functions is even invocable using normal member syntax. However, you could take a pointer to such functions and invoke them through that pointer. `(&B::bar)(42)` is valid, if weird, call.

However, It does not specify whether the standard does not allow explicit object parameter of type-of-self implicitly convertible to particular another type.

```cpp
struct A { };
struct B {
    void foo(this A&);
    void bar(this int);
};
```

Does that mean that:

```cpp
struct A { };
struct B {
  operator A() const noexcept;
  void foo(this A);
};

// ...
// '&B::foo' is of type function pointer not pointer to member function
// because it uses explicit object parameter.
(&B::foo)(A{}); 
(&B::foo)(B{});
B{}.foo(); // will work?
```

will work?

In another case, here is a lambda. Since the type of the lambda is unutterable and is always dependent. What about the case above? (this captureless lambda is convertible to `int(*)(int, int, int)`)

```cpp
auto fib = [](this int(* self)(int, int, int), int n, int a = 0, int b = 1) {
  return n == 0 ? a : n == 1 ? b : self(n - 1, b, a + b);
};
```

Given that:

> Non-member functions, static member functions, and **explicit object member functions** match targets of **function pointer type** or reference to function type. Non-static Implicit object member functions match targets of pointer-to-member-function type. ([over.match.viable] §12.2.3)

> In all contexts, when converting to the implicit object parameter or when converting to the left operand of an assignment operation only standard conversion sequences are allowed. **[Note: When converting to the explicit object parameter, if any, user-defined conversion sequences are allowed. - end note ]** ([over.best.ics] §12.2.4.2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your first question:

```cpp
struct A { };
struct B {
  operator A() const noexcept;
  void foo(this A);
};

B{}.foo(); // will work?
```

Yes. Candidate lookup will find `B::foo`, which more or less evaluates as `foo(B{})`, which is valid due to the conversion function. This is explicitly called out in the note you cited, in [[over.ics.best]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics#general-note-5):

> [*Note 5*: When converting to the explicit object parameter, if any, user-defined conversion sequences are allowed. — *end note*]

---

This one, I'm actually not entirely sure about:

```cpp
auto fib = [](this int(* self)(int, int, int), int n, int a = 0, int b = 1) {
  return n == 0 ? a : n == 1 ? b : self(n - 1, b, a + b);
};
```

It seems exceedingly unlikely to be useful and you should probably never do this, so I don't know that it matters whether or not it's actually valid. But also am not sure what it means for examples like this:

```cpp
struct C {
    C(auto);
    void f();
};

auto lambda = [](this C c) { c.f(); }; // OK?
```

If this is convertible to a function pointer, what function pointer type exactly? If it's `void(*)()`, then which `C` are we invoking `f()` on? So it'd kind of have to be `void(*)(C)`, in which case the `fib` example definitely does not work because it's impossible to spell the function pointer type non-generically in a way that matches.

Comment: Should the function pointer type's parameter list not include the explicit object parameter as well? I doesn't seem to me that https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#closure-8 excludes it or does it not count as "_parameter_" in that sense?

Comment: @user17732522 The wording may actually be correct as-is, I updated the answer for that part.